# Directory creation (0777) using a systemd service modifies the parent directory permissions. Why?

Tags: linux, systemd

I am creating a runtime directory in **/dev/socket/** with 0777 permission using a systemd service.

Using the following command:

```
d /dev/socket/newdir 0777 root root -
```

After reboot, the new directory is successfully created with 0777 permission. But the parent directory's (/dev/socket) permission got changed from 0777 to 0755. Why is that so?

Note: The parent directory /dev/socket actually had 0777 permission.

Comment: What directory has what permission?  Your question is very confusing.

Comment: Edited to make the question more clear.